# Oracle SQL Like

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get all the addresses that start with letters, when I say a specific letter there are no problems.

```
    SELECT customer_name, customer_address 
FROM Customers
WHERE CUSTOMER_ADDRESS LIKE 'A%';
```

But when I try from A-Z, it does not show any result

```
SELECT customer_name, customer_address 
FROM Customers
WHERE CUSTOMER_ADDRESS LIKE '[A-Z]%';
```

Someone knows what i'm doing wrong? (i already try without [], '', %[A-Z]%, [a-z]%)

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: `[A-Z]` is regex syntax and that's not supported by Sal at least the same way. You might want to look for proper sql syntax for using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex_like

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (CUSTOMER_ADDRESS , '^[A-Z]');
```

Answer (score 2):

Valid wildchars for `LIKE` are `%` for an unknown number of characters and `_` for one character. So `LIKE '[A-Z]%'` looks for strings starting with the character `[`, followed by `A`, followed by `-`, ...

You want `REGEXP_LIKE` instead:

```
SELECT customer_name, customer_address 
FROM Customers
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(customer_address, '^[A-Z].*');
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using ASCII character and you want to be able to use an index, you can phrase this as:

```
WHERE CUSTOMER_ADDRESS >= 'A' AND
      CUSTOMER_ADDRESS < '['  -- the ASCII character one bigger than 'Z'
```

This is a bit arcane, but it does a direct comparison so can use indexes (and even without indexes would be marginally faster).